# Battery on iPhone 6S Plus quickly diminishes and reboots every few seconds after being in cold weather.

Tags: iphone, battery

After my iPhone 6S Plus was in cold weather -8*C Skiing with the iPhone near my body, my iPhone loses battery very quickly, decreases by 1 percent per 15 seconds just on the home screen with no apps open. Every few seconds of use the iPhone screen will go black and a circular loading sign will appear (no Apple logo) and it will go to the password screen soon after. I know that cold weather increases the internal resistance of Li-ion batteries, but surely no permenant damage when it was not even being used?

Answer (score 3):

you might wanna take this opportunity - Apple have sent a message to their customers offering $29 battery replacements for any and all iPhone 6 / iPhone 6s etc phones that are experiencing crashes/reboots and worse battery life. Hope it helps! The link is at

https://www.apple.com/iphone-battery-and-performance/

Here are the bits that might be of most use to you as information:

> To address our customers’ concerns, to recognize their loyalty and to
> regain the trust of anyone who may have doubted Apple’s intentions,
> we’ve decided to take the following steps:
>
> Apple is reducing the price
> of an out-of-warranty iPhone battery replacement by $50 — from $79 to
> $29 — for anyone with an iPhone 6 or later whose battery needs to be
> replaced, available worldwide through December 2018. Details will be
> provided soon on apple.com.
>
> Early in 2018, we will issue an iOS
> software update with new features that give users more visibility into
> the health of their iPhone’s battery, so they can see for themselves
> if its condition is affecting performance.
>
> As always, our team is
> working on ways to make the user experience even better, including
> improving how we manage performance and avoid unexpected shutdowns as
> batteries age.

Comment: Good shout. It's worth a go if you cant solve it with a software based approach. If the new battery doesn't solve it, at least it was quite cheap(and professionally done).

Comment: Have them run a diagnostics test too on it. Any information it provides can further assist others.